# No puedo simular evento en unit test usando Jasmine-Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, unittest, jasmine, angular15

El valor de un filtro es inicialmente '', y despues de presionar el teclado y con el evento keyup el valor deberia ser el actual del componente filtro. He codificado el siguiente unit test, pero no puedo conseguir el valor actualizado tras el evento, siempre sigo obteniendo el valor inicial, con lo que falla el expect final.

```
describe('Component', () => {
    let component: Component1;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component1>;
    let mockDialog: MatDialog;
    let mockDataService: Service1;
    let mockToastr: ToastrService;
    let mockPaginator: MatPaginator;
    let mockSort: MatSort;
    let mockFilterElement: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [Component1],
            imports: [MatPaginatorModule],
            providers: [
                { provide: MatDialog, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialog', ['open']) },
                { provide: Service1, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('Service1', ['fetchData', 'update', 'getAll']) },
                { provide: ToastrService, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('ToastrService', ['success', 'error']) },
            ],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component1);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        mockDialog = TestBed.inject(MatDialog);
        mockDataService = TestBed.inject(Service1);
        mockToastr = TestBed.inject(ToastrService);

        mockPaginator = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatPaginator', ['previousPage', 'nextPage']);
        mockSort = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatSort', ['sort']);

        mockFilterElement = new ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>(document.createElement('input'));

        component.dialog = mockDialog;
        component.dataService = mockDataService;
        component.paginator = mockPaginator;
        component.sort = mockSort;
        component.filter = mockFilterElement;

        component.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(null, mockPaginator, mockSort);

        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should handle filter changes', async () => {
        const filterValue = 'test';
        mockFilterElement.nativeElement.value = filterValue;

        await component.ngOnInit();
                
        const event = new Event('keyup');
        mockFilterElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);

        expect(component.dataSource.filter).toBe(filterValue);
  

      });
    // More Tests...
    
    });
```

Cualquier ayuda sera bien agradecida. Gracias de antemano por vuestro soporte.